# File upload/download between salesforce and another server through sftp

Tags: salesforce, sftp, apex-code, visualforce

I am new to salesforce application. I am using Apex. My requirement is to upload/download file between salesforce and our server through sftp. Is there any sftp client for salesforce or how can I do it? Any idea/link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce only supports http(s) for connectivity, there's no sftp support.

Comment: You mean it is not possible upload/download to/from sftp server (our own server) using apex code on salesforce.

Comment: In this case, my plan is salesforce will be a client.

Comment: You cannot be an SFTP client from apex, you can be an HTTP(S) client, but not SFTP.